# React to Laravel CSRF token mismatch

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, csrf-token

So I've tried a lot of solution online but none had work, I always get 419 error when sending a post request from react to laravel.

cors.php

```
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

method for fetching CSRF Token

```
  const csrf = () => axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
    withCredentials: true,
  } ).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

post request

```
 await csrf();
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/login`, payload, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)XSRF-TOKEN\s*=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, '$1'),
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      withXSRFToken: true,
      
    })
```

I've checked if the token sent in the header is the same but I still get CSRF token mismatch
as you can see here, the cookies are the same on the request header:
[Browser Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5fTT.png)

[CSRF token on request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKg5Y.png)

Comment: I think you need to first get the csrf cookie before doing the actual post request(login). Check https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#csrf-protection.

Comment: I did get the cookie as you can see I had await csrf() above the login request

Comment: i meant you need to do a get request to sanctum first before doing your post request. Did you try what the docs said?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when react SPA and laravel are on different domains this combination works:

- set SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in laravel .env
- make your own api/login route

You can check this example: https://github.com/erikroznbeker/sanctum-laravel-csrf